# how disallow only (a-zA-Z) in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how disallow only (a-zA-Z) in asp.net(C#) in textbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check key code when user types something in text box.
For example:

```
function checknumber(e, control) {
    isIE = document.all ? 1 : 0
    keyEntry = !isIE ? e.which : event.keyCode;
    if ((keyEntry > '47') && (keyEntry < '58'))
        return true;
    else if (keyEntry == '8')
        return true;
    else if (keyEntry == '46')
        return false;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and then call this function on key press:

```
onkeypress="return checknumber(event, this);"
```

This code allows only digits in textbox. You can change it as required.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an ASP.NET validation control to limit the values that will be accepted by the textbox when it is submitted. I'd suggest using the [`RegularExpressionValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx).

The benefit of this approach is that it will work on both the server and the client-side ensuring that the input will be valid when processed on the server. Just be sure, on the server side, to call the page's `Validate` method and to check if the page is valid (`IsValid`) before processing the value of the textbox.

You can combine this approach with the AJAX control toolkit that **safi** mentions (or a jQuery plugin) to improve the experience for end users.

Using the ASP.NET `RegularExpressionValidator` would look something like this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="textBoxToValidate" runat="server"/>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="regularExpressionValidator" ControlToValidate="textBoxToValidate" ValidationExpression="[^a-zA-Z]*" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Alphabet characters are not allowed" runat="server"/>
```

Then on the server side:

```
private void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Validate();  // force server-side validation controls to validate
    if (IsValid)
    {
        // validation successful
        // you can safely use textBoxToValidate.Text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can disallow it clientside via javascript, it isn't recommended to only use clientside validation. Just apply your validation server side, only way to be sure you only get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

here you can see that in asp.net using ajax you can restrict the type of data you want to be in the text box

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx

Comment: Please add a bit of context to the link - at the moment this looks like spam (although it isn't).

Comment: @Blowski thanks, well here you can see that in asp.net using ajax you can restrict the type of data you want to be in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Use, a code some thing like this in javascript

```
function isCharacter(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and if you dont know i am passing the Textbox onkeypress event code also

```
onkeypress="return isCharacter(event)"
```